# Не работает пессимистическая блокировка

Tags: java, hibernate

Пытаюсь сделать небольшой пример (oracle, hibernate) чтобы работала песс блокировка.

```
public class AccountDAOImpl implements AccountDAO {

    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    public void updateDescExclamationPoint() {

        System.out.println("updateDescExclamationPoint. start");

        TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
        transactionTemplate.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
        System.out.println("transactionTemplate: " + transactionTemplate.getPropagationBehavior());
        transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
            @Override
            protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
                try {
                    Account acc = (Account)getSession().get(Account.class, 1,  LockOptions.UPGRADE);
                    acc.setDescription(acc.getDescription() + "!");

                    // Обработка
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    status.setRollbackOnly();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        System.out.println("updateDescExclamationPoint. stop");
    }

    public void updateDesc413() {

        System.out.println("updateDesc413. start");

        TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
        transactionTemplate.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
        System.out.println("transactionTemplate: " + transactionTemplate.getPropagationBehavior());
        transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
            @Override
            protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
                try {
                    // Обработка
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    System.out.println("updateDesc413. start BLOCK");
                    Account acc = (Account)getSession().get(Account.class, 1, LockOptions.UPGRADE);
                    System.out.println("updateDesc413. stop BLOCK");

                    acc.setDescription(acc.getDescription() + "413");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    status.setRollbackOnly();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        System.out.println("updateDesc413. stop");
    }

    public void setTransactionManager(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Запускаю выполнение методов в двух разных потоках:

```
    public void test() {

        System.out.println("CriteriaTestImpl. start");

        Thread threadExclPoint = new Thread(() -> { accountDAO.updateDescExclamationPoint(); });
        threadExclPoint.start();

        Thread thread413 = new Thread(() -> { accountDAO.updateDesc413(); });
        thread413.start();

        try {
            threadExclPoint.join();
            thread413.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            System.out.println("InterruptedException: " + ie.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("CriteriaTestImpl. stop");

    }
```

Лог в котором комитятся обе транзакции, но результаты фиксируются только от первой:

```
CriteriaTestImpl. start
updateDescExclamationPoint. start
transactionTemplate: 3
updateDesc413. start
transactionTemplate: 3
2020-11-04 12:24:03 DEBUG DataSourceTransactionManager:367 - Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2020-11-04 12:24:03 DEBUG DataSourceTransactionManager:367 - Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2020-11-04 12:24:03 DEBUG DriverManagerDataSource:142 - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522:orcl]
2020-11-04 12:24:03 DEBUG DriverManagerDataSource:142 - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522:orcl]
2020-11-04 12:24:03 DEBUG DataSourceTransactionManager:206 - Acquired Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@39096ceb] for JDBC transaction
2020-11-04 12:24:03 DEBUG DataSourceTransactionManager:206 - Acquired Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@1bddaff8] for JDBC transaction
2020-11-04 12:24:03 DEBUG DataSourceTransactionManager:223 - Switching JDBC Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@39096ceb] to manual commit
2020-11-04 12:24:03 DEBUG DataSourceTransactionManager:223 - Switching JDBC Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@1bddaff8] to manual commit
HibernateLog --> 12:24:03 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select account0_.id as id1_0_0_, account0_.CLIENT_ID as CLIENT_ID5_0_0_, account0_.description as description2_0_0_, account0_.num as num3_0_0_, account0_.Version as Version4_0_0_ from account_test account0_ where account0_.id=? for update
2020-11-04 12:24:03 DEBUG SQL:109 - select account0_.id as id1_0_0_, account0_.CLIENT_ID as CLIENT_ID5_0_0_, account0_.description as description2_0_0_, account0_.num as num3_0_0_, account0_.Version as Version4_0_0_ from account_test account0_ where account0_.id=? for update
2020-11-04 12:24:03 DEBUG DriverManagerDataSource:142 - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522:orcl]
HibernateLog --> 12:24:03 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [1]
2020-11-04 12:24:03 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [1]
HibernateLog --> 12:24:03 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor - extracted value ([CLIENT_ID5_0_0_] : [INTEGER]) - [1]
2020-11-04 12:24:03 TRACE BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([CLIENT_ID5_0_0_] : [INTEGER]) - [1]
HibernateLog --> 12:24:03 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor - extracted value ([description2_0_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Bochan]
2020-11-04 12:24:03 TRACE BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([description2_0_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Bochan]
HibernateLog --> 12:24:03 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor - extracted value ([num3_0_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [12345]
2020-11-04 12:24:03 TRACE BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([num3_0_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [12345]
HibernateLog --> 12:24:03 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor - extracted value ([Version4_0_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [20]
2020-11-04 12:24:03 TRACE BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([Version4_0_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [20]
HibernateLog --> 12:24:03 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select client0_.id as id1_1_0_, client0_.name as name2_1_0_ from client_test client0_ where client0_.id=?
2020-11-04 12:24:03 DEBUG SQL:109 - select client0_.id as id1_1_0_, client0_.name as name2_1_0_ from client_test client0_ where client0_.id=?
HibernateLog --> 12:24:03 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [1]
2020-11-04 12:24:03 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [1]
HibernateLog --> 12:24:03 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor - extracted value ([name2_1_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Bocharov Dima]
2020-11-04 12:24:03 TRACE BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([name2_1_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Bocharov Dima]
HibernateLog --> 12:24:03 TRACE org.hibernate.type.CollectionType - Created collection wrapper: [ru.sbrf.test.spring.tx.model.Client.accounts#1]
2020-11-04 12:24:03 TRACE CollectionType:783 - Created collection wrapper: [ru.sbrf.test.spring.tx.model.Client.accounts#1]
updateDesc413. start BLOCK
HibernateLog --> 12:24:06 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select account0_.id as id1_0_0_, account0_.CLIENT_ID as CLIENT_ID5_0_0_, account0_.description as description2_0_0_, account0_.num as num3_0_0_, account0_.Version as Version4_0_0_ from account_test account0_ where account0_.id=? for update
2020-11-04 12:24:06 DEBUG SQL:109 - select account0_.id as id1_0_0_, account0_.CLIENT_ID as CLIENT_ID5_0_0_, account0_.description as description2_0_0_, account0_.num as num3_0_0_, account0_.Version as Version4_0_0_ from account_test account0_ where account0_.id=? for update
2020-11-04 12:24:06 DEBUG DriverManagerDataSource:142 - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522:orcl]
HibernateLog --> 12:24:06 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [1]
2020-11-04 12:24:06 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [1]
HibernateLog --> 12:24:06 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor - extracted value ([CLIENT_ID5_0_0_] : [INTEGER]) - [1]
2020-11-04 12:24:06 TRACE BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([CLIENT_ID5_0_0_] : [INTEGER]) - [1]
HibernateLog --> 12:24:06 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor - extracted value ([description2_0_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Bochan]
2020-11-04 12:24:06 TRACE BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([description2_0_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Bochan]
HibernateLog --> 12:24:06 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor - extracted value ([num3_0_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [12345]
2020-11-04 12:24:06 TRACE BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([num3_0_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [12345]
HibernateLog --> 12:24:06 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor - extracted value ([Version4_0_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [20]
2020-11-04 12:24:06 TRACE BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([Version4_0_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [20]
HibernateLog --> 12:24:06 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select client0_.id as id1_1_0_, client0_.name as name2_1_0_ from client_test client0_ where client0_.id=?
2020-11-04 12:24:06 DEBUG SQL:109 - select client0_.id as id1_1_0_, client0_.name as name2_1_0_ from client_test client0_ where client0_.id=?
HibernateLog --> 12:24:06 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [1]
2020-11-04 12:24:06 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [1]
HibernateLog --> 12:24:06 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor - extracted value ([name2_1_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Bocharov Dima]
2020-11-04 12:24:06 TRACE BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([name2_1_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Bocharov Dima]
HibernateLog --> 12:24:06 TRACE org.hibernate.type.CollectionType - Created collection wrapper: [ru.sbrf.test.spring.tx.model.Client.accounts#1]
2020-11-04 12:24:06 TRACE CollectionType:783 - Created collection wrapper: [ru.sbrf.test.spring.tx.model.Client.accounts#1]
updateDesc413. stop BLOCK
2020-11-04 12:24:06 DEBUG SessionFactoryUtils:103 - Flushing Hibernate Session on transaction synchronization
HibernateLog --> 12:24:06 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - update account_test set CLIENT_ID=?, description=?, num=?, Version=? where id=?
2020-11-04 12:24:06 DEBUG SQL:109 - update account_test set CLIENT_ID=?, description=?, num=?, Version=? where id=?
HibernateLog --> 12:24:06 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [1]
2020-11-04 12:24:06 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [1]
HibernateLog --> 12:24:06 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [Bochan413]
2020-11-04 12:24:06 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [Bochan413]
HibernateLog --> 12:24:06 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [12345]
2020-11-04 12:24:06 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [12345]
HibernateLog --> 12:24:06 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [4] as [BIGINT] - [20]
2020-11-04 12:24:06 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [4] as [BIGINT] - [20]
HibernateLog --> 12:24:06 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [5] as [INTEGER] - [1]
2020-11-04 12:24:06 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [5] as [INTEGER] - [1]
2020-11-04 12:24:06 DEBUG DataSourceTransactionManager:759 - Initiating transaction commit
2020-11-04 12:24:06 DEBUG DataSourceTransactionManager:269 - Committing JDBC transaction on Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@39096ceb]
2020-11-04 12:24:06 DEBUG DataSourceTransactionManager:327 - Releasing JDBC Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@39096ceb] after transaction
2020-11-04 12:24:06 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:327 - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
updateDesc413. start Criteria
updateDesc413. stop
2020-11-04 12:24:08 DEBUG SessionFactoryUtils:103 - Flushing Hibernate Session on transaction synchronization
HibernateLog --> 12:24:08 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - update account_test set CLIENT_ID=?, description=?, num=?, Version=? where id=?
2020-11-04 12:24:08 DEBUG SQL:109 - update account_test set CLIENT_ID=?, description=?, num=?, Version=? where id=?
HibernateLog --> 12:24:08 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [1]
2020-11-04 12:24:08 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [1]
HibernateLog --> 12:24:08 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [Bochan!]
2020-11-04 12:24:08 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [Bochan!]
HibernateLog --> 12:24:08 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [12345]
2020-11-04 12:24:08 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [12345]
HibernateLog --> 12:24:08 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [4] as [BIGINT] - [20]
2020-11-04 12:24:08 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [4] as [BIGINT] - [20]
HibernateLog --> 12:24:08 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [5] as [INTEGER] - [1]
2020-11-04 12:24:08 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [5] as [INTEGER] - [1]
2020-11-04 12:24:08 DEBUG DataSourceTransactionManager:759 - Initiating transaction commit
2020-11-04 12:24:08 DEBUG DataSourceTransactionManager:269 - Committing JDBC transaction on Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@1bddaff8]
2020-11-04 12:24:08 DEBUG DataSourceTransactionManager:327 - Releasing JDBC Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@1bddaff8] after transaction
2020-11-04 12:24:08 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:327 - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
updateDescExclamationPoint. stop
CriteriaTestImpl. stop
```

Первый поток захватывает блокировку на 5 сек и обновляет:

> acc.setDescription(acc.getDescription() + "!");

Второй захватывает блокировку после захвата первым потоком и обновляет:

> acc.setDescription(acc.getDescription() + "413");

Ожидаю в БД увидеть значение поля Description Bochan!413
Но в результате только Bochan!

Ничего хуже я в своей жизни не видел.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, в конфигурации поменял

```
 <bean id="transactionManager"
 class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
     <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
 </bean>
```

на

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```